# Codeigniter - Consulta no DB

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Boa noite!

Preciso retornar o valor de uma tabela no codeigniter mas esta acusando o erro abaixo:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: nome
>
> Filename: paineladmin/categorias.php
>
> Line Number: 7

Mas minha função no model esta correta, segue abaixo:

```
public function get_bynome($nome=NULL){
    if($nome != NULL):
        $this->db->where('nome', $nome);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        return $this->db->get('categorias');
    else:
        return FALSE;
    endif;
}
```

E a chamada na view esta assim:

```
echo '<div class="small-12 columns">';
    echo breadcrumb();
    $query = $this->categorias->get_bynome($nome)->row();
    erros_validacao();
    get_msg('msgok');       
    echo form_open('categorias/cadastrar', array('class'=>'custom'));
    echo form_fieldset('Cadastrar nova categoria');
    echo form_label('Nome');
    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<div class="small-5 columns">';
    echo form_input(array('name'=>'nome'), set_value('nome'), 'autofocus');
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo form_label('Categoria Pai');
    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<div class="small-5 columns">';
    echo form_dropdown('Categoria Pai', $query->nome, 'Selecione uma opção');
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';



public function cadastrar(){
  //esta_logado();
  $data['query'] = $this->categorias->get_bynome($nome)->row();    
  $this->load->view("categorias", $data);
```

Parece que a variável não esta declarada algo assim, não achei o erro.

Comment: Qual dos 2 é o arquivo paineladmin/categorias.php?

Comment: A view, o debaixo

Comment: Eu não sei como o CI renderiza a view... `$query = $this->categorias->get_bynome($nome)->row()` a view está recebendo a variável $nome certo? De um `var_dump( $nome )` no inicio da view.

Comment: Sim, a view esta recebendo a variavel $nome da função get_bynome da model. Não adiantou com var_dump($nome) hehe

Comment: Poderia colocar o código que chama a view?

Comment: public function cadastrar(){
  //esta_logado();
  $data['query'] = $this->categorias->get_bynome($nome)->row();
  $this->load->view("categorias", $data);

Comment: Se `$nome` vem de um POST/GET, vc deveria recuperar assim: `$nome = $this->input->post('nome');` isso no `cadastrar()`.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que pude perceber, esse seu erro é por causa que não esta passando a variavel para a view, isso deve ser feito a partir do seu controller, e não sei se estou certo, mas essa parte é do seu controller correto:

```
public function cadastrar(){
  //esta_logado();
  $data['query'] = $this->categorias->get_bynome($nome)->row();    
  $this->load->view("categorias", $data);
```

se sim, vc deveria ter feito assim

```
public function cadastrar(){
  //esta_logado();
  $data['query'] = $this->categorias->get_bynome($nome)->row();    
  $data['nome'] = $nome; //passar a variavel nome para a view
  $this->load->view("categorias", $data);
```

pelo tempo que vc fez a pergunta já deve até ter resolvido, mas só confirma se era isso mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Erros do tipo NOTICE no PHP podem ser ignorados chamando a seguinte função no começo do arquivo:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

No Codeigniter, essa função é chamada no arquivo index.php. Você pode verificar entre as linhas 31 e 47 no código fonte do framework:

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.2.0/index.php